# Iot Edge on Windows 10 Iot Core on RaspBerry Pi 3B

Tags: azure, raspberry-pi3, iot, windows-iot-core-10, azure-iot-edge

I'm trying to get IoT Edge Runtime installed on a Windows 10 IoT Core (build 17763 through the IoT Dashboard tool) on a Raspberry Pi 3b (not the plus version!). I'm following this [instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge-windows) . The IoT Core seems to be running fine. I can connect to it through the device portal. I have a remote PowerShell session opened to the device and I run the command that gets and runs the IotEdgeSecurityDaemon.ps1 script using the command from the mentioned instruction:

```
. {Invoke-WebRequest -useb aka.ms/iotedge-win} | Invoke-Expression; `
Install-SecurityDaemon -Manual -ContainerOs Windows -DeviceConnectionString 'xxxxxx'
```

with the connection string being the primary connection string from the IoT Edge device that I added beforehand in the Iot Hub. That all looks fine.

I can see it getting moby-engine (this install script should take care of the installation of the required container engine?) and other prereqs it needs, but in the end, it can't start the iotedge runtime service. This seems related to the moby-engine not running or not being installed (without any logging at all). I have found an alternative  IotEdgeSecurityDaemon.ps1 script but before I start using that, I'd like to ask if anyone else has seen the same or similar problem with this particular setup.

regards,
derk

Comment: Just a quick comment that you don't need IoTEdge to connect to IoT Hub and you can have IoT Hub connected devices running on Win IoT Core - just not Edge devices

Answer (score 1):

Windows ARM architecture is not yet supported by IoT Edge. AMD64-based IoT Core platforms should work.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/support#tier-1 for more details.

Comment: ok you're saying that although I can install a windows os on the raspberry pi, i still can't use iot edge on that because it's not supported on iot core on an arm processor architecture? Makes sense. I guess i was assuming that microsoft would make sure to have iot edge working anywhere iot core was installed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have report the requirement to Microsoft. Glad to hear the user voice for improving the experience on Windows Product.

Comment: @derk - That is a reasonable assumption . This is a point in time thing, Windows ARM support is on our roadmap.

Comment: I have since tried this configuration on a MinnowBoard Turbot MBT2220 (x86) and seen this work. Thanks for your time!